# The minimum number that cannot be summed by $11$ or fewer factorials.

Tags: factorial

What is the smallest positive integer one can find impossible to create by $11$ or less factorials?

I only know how to limit the possibilities, but not how to actually solve this. I'm assuming that this is a simple trick in a logic question, but I can't seem to see how to start, nor figure out what type of question this is. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: $1$? ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$<2!$ you need one factorial, $1!=1$

$<3!$ you might need another $2 \times 2!$

$<4!$ you might need another $3 \times 3!$

$<5!$ you might need another $4 \times 4!$

$<2\times 5!$ you might need another $1 \times 5!$ - we could need $11$ factorials at this point

At $3\times 5!-1=359$, then, you should need $12$ factorial to sum to this number.

(see also [factorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system))

Comment: So the strategy is to try numbers 1 less than a multiple of n factorial?

Comment: @user406996 Such numbers require a lot of factorials to sum to, for sure.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I understand how you did it now.

Answer (score 1):

1 cannot be summed as 11 factorials.

Does your question mean "no more than 11 factorials"?

(after your edit)

it looks like task of dynamical programming - calculate for an n the minimal number of the factorials in the sum.

Comment: Yes, thanks for catching that! :)

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to this with just pencil and paper?

Comment: Try to precalculate answer(it is  359 ^_^) and create a proof after

Comment: You can build up to the number knowing that 1 less than factorials is hard to create as a sum of factorials :) Thanks for pointing out the Dynamical Programming approach!